# When I replace 195/55/14 with 165/65/14, what may I expect?

Tags: tires

I learned that my original tyre size 195/55/14 is not being produced any longer.

Because I calculated I can miss up to three hundred a year for kilometer allowance and that I insist to keep my stock rims because it is a classic car I learned that 165/65/14 has the exact same circumference.

My car has abs. Would this be a problem for abs? And if not, what kind of driving behaviour I may expect?

Comment: ABS could care if you changed the tyres on one axle and not the other. Perminant 4wd could similarly object! But different makes of tyres can be somewhat different in dimensions despite the same claimed size. A 185/60 14 might be a closer match and be more available (was a very common tyre size)

Answer (score 1):

The ABS system doesn't care about tire size.  The biggest concern when going to a different size is fender clearance especially loaded and while turning.  As long as the replacement tire is reasonably similar in size, you shouldn't have any problems.

Is there a club or owner's group for this type of car?  Others there may have some specific size recommendations of known-to-fit sizes.

As an added resource, this web site:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

Can be useful in comparing different sizes.  According to it, the two sizes you've mentioned are nearly identical in all aspects except for TREAD.  So it looks like the 165/65-14 will fit fine although it will be quite a bit narrower.

You might consider a 185/55R14 tire as this is closer in all dimensions to the original tires.

Comment: Nice find on that tire size page. Thx.

Comment: I have the oppurtunity to put a set of rims with 185/60/14 tyres under my car for a very low price. I'm not sure which would be better dimensional size but those I have have here have good profile. More important I also learned that 165/65/14 has a a maximum of speed 190 km per hour and my car should be able to reach 210 km per hour. So I can't install any 165/65/14 tyre. Thank you for helping me out.